# Reuse specific lines of code

Tags: python

Suppose I use this block of code very often in my Python file

```
if x == 1:
  x += 1
else:
  x -= 1
```

Is there a way to "copy" this code, so that I don't have to type these four lines repeatedly throughout the file?

Comment: Have you heard of a thing called function? :)

Comment: My +1 as beginners should be expected to be beginners. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes define yourself a function for it:

```
def flip_member(x):
    if x == 1:
        x += 1
    else:
        x -= 1
    return x
```

Then you can call the function from anywhere in your code instead of rewriting the same logic.

Comment: Yeah I get mixed up sometimes. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the other answers, you can write a function of x and set x equal to the function's result.

Some alternatives are writing the expression in a simpler form:

```
x = x+1 if x==1 else x-1
```

The above computes the same new value of x as the four lines of code in the question.  But if you just want to toggle x back and forth between the values 1 and 2, note that 3-1 is 2 and 3-2 is 1, so you can say  – to toggle between 1 and 2 –

```
x = 3-x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def manipulate(x):
    return x+1 if x==1 else x-1

myVal = 10
myVal = manipulate(myVal)
print myVal
>>> 9
```

OR:

```
manipulate = lambda x: x+1 if x==1 else x-1
myVal = manipulate(myVal)
print myVal
>>> 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Or an even shorter one-liner:

```
x = x - 1 + (x==1) * 2
```